# Flutter RawDatagramSocket too many files Error

Tags: flutter, sockets, udp

I have to send every 200ms a request to a raspberry pi. But after some time I get the error:

> Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Failed to create datagram socket (OS Error: Too many open files, errno = 24), address = 0.0.0.0, port = 0
> #0      _NativeSocket.bindDatagram (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1015:7)

Code:

```
class UDPSender {    
  late Future<RawDatagramSocket> _socket;

  UDPSender () {
    _socket =  RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);
  }

  void sendRelaisAndEngineCommandList({required List<RelaisCommand> relaisCommand, required List<EngineCommand> engineCommand}) async {

    RawDatagramSocket sender =  await _socket;

    GangwayCommand command = GangwayCommand();
    command.timestamp =
        Int64(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch).toUnsigned(64);
    command.relaisCommands.addAll(relaisCommand);
    command.engineCommands.addAll(engineCommand);

    Uint8List bytesOut = command.writeToBuffer();


    if (brConstants.encryptionEnabled) {
      bytesOut = await _encryptMessage(bytesOut);
    }

    var dataLength = await sender.send(
        bytesOut,
        InternetAddress(HiveStorageBR.getBrHostname()),
            HiveStorageBR.getUdpPort());
  }

  void close() async {
    (await _socket).close();
  }



  static Future<Uint8List> _encryptMessage(Uint8List message) async {
    // AES-CBC with 128 bit keys and HMAC-SHA256 authentication.
    final algorithm = AesCbc.with128bits(
      macAlgorithm: MacAlgorithm.empty,
    );
    //final secretKey = await algorithm.newSecretKey();

    final secretKey = SecretKey(base64.decode(HiveStorageBR.getEncKey()));
    //final nonce = algorithm.newNonce();

    // Encrypt
    final secretBox = await algorithm.encrypt(
      message,
      secretKey: secretKey,
    );

    var json = <String, dynamic>{
      'iv': base64.encode(secretBox.nonce),
      'ciphertext': base64.encode(secretBox.cipherText),
    };


    return Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(jsonEncode(json)));

  }
}
```

And the function which calls it:

```
class _BCState extends State<BC> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
    final UDPSender _udpSender = UDPSender();
    void _sendMessage() {
        if (_isActive) {
            _udpSender.sendRelaisAndEngineCommandList(
                  relaisCommand: _relaisCommandDirectionHandler(),
                  engineCommand: _getEngineCommandList());
        
              Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 200), () {
                _sendMessage();
              });
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: Where do you have this line of code? `final UDPSender _udpSender = UDPSender();` It's probably being called multiple times.

Comment: I updated it right now

Comment: Try changing `0` to a fixed port number, say, `5555` in `bind`. If bind is being called twice the second will fail and you should be able to see where that got called from. Also it's a bit strange to hold onto the future rather than the socket. Consider changing `late Future<RawDatagramSocket> _socket;` to `RawDatagramSocket? _socket` and dropping the await from the references: `_socket?.close();` Of course, you'll need to tweak how to assign to _socket to an async method or a `then` on the bind.